# Finding all valid xpath from xml

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to write a program in java where in i can find all the xpath for the given xml.I found out the link on the internet [xpath generator](http://www.phurnace.com/blog/automatically-generate-xpath-expressions-in-java-2.html) but it does not work when one element can repeat multipletimes for example if we have xml like the following :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>A</FirstName>
        <LastName>B</LastName>
        <MiddleName>C</MiddleName>

    </Name>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>D</FirstName>
        <LastName>E</LastName>
        <MiddleName>S</MiddleName>
    </Name>
</Report>
```

It will produce xpaths :-
/Report/Name/firstname for both firstname nodes.
but the expected should be /Report/Name[1](http://www.phurnace.com/blog/automatically-generate-xpath-expressions-in-java-2.html)/firstname and /Report/Name[2]/firstname

Any ideas?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the number of valid XPath expressions for any given XML document is infinite. What are you *actually* trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have to do this yourself.

Using a SAX parser will make it straightforward. Just maintain a stack of the elements you encounter and a count so you can increment the indexes (`/Report/Name[1]`, `/Report/Name[2]`) easily.